# How to throw a 404 error in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In app.js, I have

```
// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});
```

so if I request some not exist url like `http://localhost/notfound`, above code will execute.

In exist url like `http://localhost/posts/:postId`, I would like to throw 404 error when access some not exist postId or deleted postId.

```
Posts.findOne({_id: req.params.id, deleted: false}).exec()
  .then(function(post) {
    if(!post) {
      // How to throw a 404 error, so code can jump to above 404 catch?
    }
```

Comment: Is this `Posts.findOne` called within a page request or a promise within a page request?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[In Express, a 404 isn't classed as an 'error', so to speak](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses) - the reasoning behind this is that a 404 isn't usually a sign that's something's gone wrong, it's just that the server couldn't find anything. Your best bet is to explicitly send a 404 in your route handler:

```
Posts.findOne({_id: req.params.id, deleted: false}).exec()
  .then(function(post) {
    if(!post) {
      res.status(404).send("Not found.");
    }
```

Or alternatively, if this feels like too much repeated code, you could always pull that code out into a function:

```
function notFound(res) {
    res.status(404).send("Not found.");
}

Posts.findOne({_id: req.params.id, deleted: false}).exec()
      .then(function(post) {
        if(!post) {
          notFound(res);
        }
```

I wouldn't recommend using a middleware in this situation solely because I feel like it makes the code less clear - the 404 is the direct result of the database code not finding anything, so it makes sense to have the response in the route handler.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same app.js structure, and I solved this problem in this way in the route handler:

```js
router.get('/something/:postId', function(req, res, next){
    // ...
    if (!post){
        next();
        return;
    }
    res.send('Post exists!');  // display post somehow
});
```

The `next()` function will call the next middleware which is the error404 handler if it is right after your routes in the app.js.

Comment: return next(); ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this and the end of your routers.

```
app.use('/', my_router);
....
app.use('/', my_router);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
        res.status(404).render('error/404.html');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you're probably looking for something like https://github.com/expressjs/api-error-handler
or just https://github.com/jshttp/http-errors

Answer (score 0):

Even though 404 pages are not considered an error in Express as written [here](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/faq.html#how-do-i-handle-404-responses), its really damn handy if you DO handle them like so. For instance when you are developing an API that wants consistent JSON output. The following code should help you with that:

Define a helper function `abort` to create status errors that can be easily used in your code to pass to the `next` function:

```js
// Use the `statuses` package which is also a dependency of Express.
const status = require('statuses');

const abort = (code) => {
    const err = new Error(status[code]);
    const err.status = code;
    return err;
};
```

Define the catch-all middleware for 404 pages which should be defined at the bottom of your stack (after all routes have been added). This forwards the 404 as an error:

```js
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    next(abort(404));
});
```

Lastly, the final error handler will now consistently send all errors in JSON format:

```js
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    
    if(!res.headersSent) {
        // You can define production mode here so that the stack trace will not be sent.
        const isProd = false;
        res.status(err.status || 500).json({
            error: err.toString(),
            ...(!isProd && {stack: err.stack.split('\n').map(i => i.trim())}),

        });
    }
    next(err);
});
```