# Node JS Express how can I send a 404 error if a bad request is made to third party API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling, http-status-code-404

In my Node JS server I have this route handler that sends a request to a third party API to get a username:

```
app.get('/players/:player', apiLimiter, function(request, response) {

const player = request.params.player;
const api_url = `https://api.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=${player}`;

var options = {
   method: "GET",
   observe: 'body',     
   };

   let apiRequest = https.request(api_url, options, function (res) {

    let data = "";

    res.on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk;
    }) 

    res.on("end", () => { 

           let objectParsed =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); 
           response.send(objectParsed);               
    }) 

  if(!player) {
  res.status(404).send("Not found.");
}


})
apiRequest.end();

})
```

This works fine to get a user that exists. However, if I put in a fake username to my /players page, that page still loads with a 200 status instead of getting a 404 response. The page loads and looks broken because it's not actually getting any data from the API.

I feel like this is a dumb question .. In my research I have found how to handle errors if it's just the route, and not if it's the route dependent on the path parameter as in /players/:player

I found a question that was similar to mine ([How to throw a 404 error in express.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36837531/how-to-throw-a-404-error-in-express-js)) and I tried using an If statement: `if (!player){res.status(404).send("Not found."); }` but no dice. Am I using this if statement in the wrong place?

How can I get my Node JS server to respond with a 404 if the user from the database doesn't exist?

Comment: It is working as per the code. In first sight you've assigned the value of player to the variable but you're not checking anywhere if this player is available or not. that's why the value still remains through the get request and you're not getting the 404 error. because you're only checking `!player` but as per your code you'll always get the player.

Comment: What does `request.params.player` actually contain when you put in a fake name? As @JuhilSomaiya says, even though it's an error, it might still return some kind of value in `request.params.player`. So when you check with `!player` it will still return true. So unless that value is empty, null or false it will return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the result of the API call and see if you got valid data back and send the 404 there.  I also added a check to make sure something was passed for the player name and send back a 400 (bad request) if there's no player specified at all:

```
app.get('/players/:player', apiLimiter, function(request, response) {

    const player = request.params.player;
    if (!player) {
        res.status(400).send("No player specified.");
        return;
    }

    const api_url = `https://api.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=${player}`;

    var options = {
        method: "GET",
        observe: 'body',
    };

    let apiRequest = https.request(api_url, options, function(res) {

        let data = "";

        res.on("data", chunk => {
            data += chunk;
        })

        res.on("end", () => {

            let objectParsed = JSON.parse(data);
            // test objectParsed here
            if (!some condition in objectParsed) {
                res.status(404).send("No data for that player name.");
            } else {
                response.send(objectParsed);
            }
        });
    });
    apiRequest.end();
});
```

Also, you don't want `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` here.  Your data is already a string.  Just do `JSON.parse(data)`.

FYI, if you use a small http request library such as [`got()`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), this code gets a lot simpler as it accumulates the response and parses the JSON for you in one line of code as in:

```
let data = await got(options).json()
```

Comment: Thanks! Definitely feels like a dumb question now but I was kind of almost close (meh maybe not too much). I ended up using `if ( objectParsed.includes('errors') ) {   response.status(404).send("No data for that player name."); }` to get it to work. 'errors' in this case is in response sent from the third party api if the user is not found from their database. Thanks again!